# Accessing a Mac application remotely from Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, remote-desktop, things-for-mac

I am a fav of a Mac applications called [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/), but I use Windows (sometimes Linux) as my primary operating system. I do have a work macbook sitting at office that runs Things.

While it may be possible to use VNC to access the Mac desktop remotely, what I specifically want is to access only the Things application from my Windows desktop *as if* it is a local application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but this appears to do what you want: Share only a specific window (or application) rather than the entire screen, using VNC. http://shared-app-vnc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

VNC is built in so you can easily use that...

```
System Preferences 
-> Sharing 
-> Select Screen Sharing
-> Click Computer Settings
-> Check off VNC viewers may control screen with password
-> Enter a password
-> Turn Screen Sharing on
```

Now you can access your MAC via VNC.  This shares the entire system.  If you want just a specific window to be shared you may want to look at this: http://shared-app-vnc.sourceforge.net/

(I've never personally used that but I hear it works)

Good luck